# Can Ord be defined for a tuple in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to define to a specific Ord function for a tuple/type alias, as opposed to a struct? I am hoping to stash a group of tuples on a BinaryHeap, but I want them to be ordered in the heap based only on one of the fields of the tuple.

I am picturing something like this (which doesn't compile):

```
type QNode = (String, u32, i32);

impl Ord for QNode {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        self.1.cmp(&other.1);
    }
}
```

I can define a Struct to push onto the heap, but it would feel more lightweight to just use the type alias.

Comment: No, you can't do that. First, `Ord` already has a blanket implementation for tuple. You need specialization to get around it, which is still unstable. Second, you are implementing a trait you don't own for a type you don't own, which violates the orphan rule.

Comment: Ord is already implemented for tuples where all its members also implement Ord.

Comment: A tuple struct would be perfectly fine: `struct QNode(String, u32, i32);`, circumventing both issues.

Comment: @edwardw You should copy your two comments into an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Tuple struct does not solve the problem.

Given the following struct:

```
struct MyStruct(usize, usize, usize);

(10, 100, 200)
(11, 0, 0)

In a max heap - (11, 0, 0) would come first.
```